# Tips for organizing one's own favorites?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

While some has only zero or a few favorite posts, I have ever-growing number of favorites. Sometimes I wonder what if I cannot locate one post easily? Unlike the way one organizes his/her computer files by hierarchy of directories or by some software, it would be nice to learn some tips for organizing one's own favorites. Thanks!

Comment: Use browser bookmarks?

Comment: @kinokijuf: Nice. Thanks!

Comment: But I cannot carry my browser everywhere from where I log into this site :)

Comment: @Swapan: if "your browser" is Firefox, there's [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/linkwad) and a number of other extensions...

Comment: And if you use Chrome you can just save it to your Google Account http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139&from=165140&rd=1

Comment: I will just mention that now there is a new feature called saves, where - unlike for bookmarks - you can have multiple lists. See the tag-info for saves [on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info) and on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info). And also this answer: [Organizing favorite posts in folders\categories](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28907#35308).