# Organizing favorite posts in folders\categories

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

Is there a way of organizing favorite posts into folders?

This is a feature I was thinking about for quite some time now. It happened to me more than once where I was looking for a certain post I remembered I pinned and it took me several minutes to find it.

One way I figured how to overcome this, is by just using my browser favorites where I can pin under folders with whatever name I choose. That is very convenient but I think it is missing the whole point of the favorites built-in feature in the site.

I would really like to be able to use custom folder names as categories of favorite posts, or maybe even using the built-in Tags as a way to filter them.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This seems rather similar to this feature request: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944). Some related posts on this meta: [Managing favourites](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3639) and [Multiple Favourites Lists](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26399).

Answer (score 8):

In October 2022, Stack Exchange completely overhauled the functionality of bookmarks:

- [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019)
- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445#375078) - October 2022

The new functionality is called "saves" rather than bookmarks. Unlike bookmarks, you can now create several lists and name them in any way you want. (But these lists are private, visible only to you - bookmarks used to be publicly visible.)

You can search among your saves [using in:saves](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=in%3Asaves). And you can add a private note to each of the saved posts.

You can find more information about saves in the announcement linked above. And also in the corresponding tag-info [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info) and [on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info).

Comment: It seems a bit buggy though. If I create lists beforehand and try to move questions from "for later" to them, they are not shown. If I create the list when I move ("create new list" in the popup), then it works.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Of course, you can post a bug report either on this meta or on [meta.se]. However, quite a lot bugs have already been reported either in [separate posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saves+bug) or in the answers [to the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019). I am not sure whether I understood you correctly, but your description seems a bit similar to the bug with empty lists reported [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383254).